# What computer requriements are needed to run Discord alongside games like Rust?

Tags: system-requirements, discord

If I'm running both Discord and a game such as Rust simultaneously, what additional requirements for my computer do I need over and above the ones needed for the game?

Answer (score 1):

If you can run Rust standalone, you shouldn't have any issue adding Discord into the mix.

The only thing that the two are likely to be competing for is RAM (Rust likely won't drive your processor too hard and Discord will be have little to no impact on your video card), you'll probably want to have 16GB of RAM, since the minimum requirement for Rust is 8GB, and I would wager you'd notice an improvement between 8GB and 16GB whether or not you're running any other applications.